# $\mathcal{T}= \{\emptyset, X, A\}$ is a topology.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $A\subset X$ a set and pruve that $\mathcal{T}= \{\emptyset, X, A\}$ is a topology.

I've got this:

[$(i)$]$\emptyset\in\mathcal{T}_m$ y $X\in\mathcal{T}_m$ for definition. but the other one?

Comment: What is the definition of a topology on a set?

Comment: You presumably need something like closed under arbitrary unions and finite intersections. Both easy to check here.

Comment: VERY straightforward from the definition of a topology and what arbitrary unions and intersections in this case would be. Remember-the open sets here are the three sets in the collection AND NOTHING ELSE.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that a **topology** on a set $X$ is a subset $\mathcal T\subseteq\mathscr P(X)$ satisfying

- $\varnothing\in\mathcal T$
- $X\in\mathcal T$
- $U,V\in\mathcal T,\ U\neq V\Rightarrow U\cap V\in\mathcal T$
- $\mathcal U\subseteq\mathcal T\Rightarrow\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal U}U\in\mathcal T$

The first two conditions are clearly satisfied in your case. For the third condition, note that there are three ways to choose two distinct elements of $\mathcal T$:

1. $\varnothing,A\in\mathcal T$ and $\varnothing\cap A=\varnothing\in\mathcal T$
2. $\varnothing, X\in\mathcal T$ and $\varnothing\cap X=\varnothing\in\mathcal T$
3. $A, X\in\mathcal T$ and $A\cap X=A\in\mathcal T$

Hence the third condition is satisfied. Can you prove the fourth condition?

Answer (score 4):

**Key idea:**
Let $X$ be a set.
Let $I$ be a well-ordered index set with a minimum $m$ and a maximum $M$.
Finally, let $U_i \; : \; i \in I$ be subsets of $X$ such that

- $U_m = X$
- $U_i \supset U_j$ for $i < j$ (the subsets are "decreasing")
- $U_M = \varnothing$

Then $\mathcal{T} = \{ U_i \}$ forms a topology on $X$.

*Proof.* $\varnothing, X \in \mathcal{T}$.  Finite intersections are in $\mathcal{T}$ because every finite subset of the totally ordered set $I$ has a maximum.  Arbitrary unions are in $\mathcal{T}$ because every subset of the well-ordered set $I$ has a minimum.

---

In your case, let $U_0 = X$, $U_1 = A$, $U_2 = \varnothing$.  Then $\{0,1,2\}$ is well-ordered in the usual way, and $U_i$ are a decreasing sequence of sets, as required.